# rs.parameters.append not executing in VBA to SQL Server code?

Tags: sql-server, vba

I have a script to send Excel table data (that matches the SQL Server ordering of headers and name) to a SQL Server. I keep getting this error:

> Error executing SQL Statement: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

on this line of code:

```
rs.Parameters.Delete
```

Complete code:

```
Sub SendDataToSQLServer()
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strConn As String
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Define the connection string
    strConn = "Provider=MSOLEDBSQL;Data Source=NICKS_LAPTOP;" & _
          "Initial Catalog=pursuant;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    ' Create a new connection object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    
    ' Open the connection
    On Error GoTo ConnectionError
    conn.Open strConn

    
' Set up a SQL query to insert data into the SQL Server table
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [Pursuant] (Parcel_ID, Landowner) VALUES (?, ?)"

' Create a new command object
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
rs.ActiveConnection = conn
rs.CommandText = strSQL
rs.CommandType = 1 ' adCmdText

' Set up a range representing the data in columns A and B
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B" & _
          ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(-4162).Row) ' xlUp

' Loop through each row in the range and insert data into SQL Server
For Each cell In rng.Rows
    ' Check if the cells in both columns are not empty
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Cells(1, 1)) And Not IsEmpty(cell.Cells(1, 2)) Then
        ' Set parameter values for Parcel ID and Landowner
        rs.Parameters.Append rs.CreateParameter("@Parcel_ID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, cell.Cells(1, 1).Value)
        rs.Parameters.Append rs.CreateParameter("@Landowner", adVarChar, adParamInput, 255, cell.Cells(1, 2).Value)
        ' Execute the SQL statement
On Error GoTo ExecutionError
rs.Execute
' Clear parameters
rs.Parameters.Delete
' Reset error handling
On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next cell
    
    ' Close the recordset
    rs.Close
    
    ' Close the connection
    conn.Close
    
    ' Clean up
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Data successfully sent to SQL Server.", vbInformation
    Exit Sub
    
ConnectionError:
        MsgBox "Error opening connection: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    
ExecutionError:
        MsgBox "Error executing SQL statement: " & Err.Description, vbExclamation

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: It'll be slow, but on every loop iteration you'll probably want to clear the rs.Parameters collection at the start and rs.Execute at the end. Otherwise your command will have n*2 parameters when it tries to execute where n is the number of rows in your Range.

Comment: Or add the parameters before the loop, and just update their values for each iteration

Comment: The syntax is delete index https://learn.microsoft.com/sr-cyrl-rs/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/delete-method-ado-parameters-collection?view=sql-server-2015 you should be able to figure out the rest